# Disable drag and drop from webbrowser control c#

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

[image: click here to see image.]

I am trying to prevent users from dragging images that display in my webbrowser control.

I tried setting webbrowser.Document.MouseOver  e.Cursor = Cursors.No Still not working.

I tried a few other ways.

I am unable to prevent images being dragged on the desktop.

Is it possible to prevent dragging of images from webbrowser control to desktop?

Comment: Not sure if you can. An alternative may be to drop a transparent panel over the top of the webbrowser control and using it to capture any events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to prevent the body element of the HTML document to handle drag operation.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://www.google.bg/search?q=stackoverflow&biw=1920&bih=950&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjw2cWH4oTQAhVG8RQKHWCWB4AQ_AUIBigB");          
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.Drag += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Body_Drag);
    }

    private void Body_Drag(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ReturnValue = false;
    }
}
```